# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "currPage"

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have the following bean's code:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PlayersReportBean

    private PlayerReportGeneratorList list = new PlayerReportGeneratorList();

    public PlayerReportGeneratorList getList() {
        return list;
    }

}

public class PlayerReportGeneratorList extends
        AbstractList<PlayerReportItem> {

    private Integer pageSize;
    private Integer currPage;
    //GET, SET, OTHER STAFF
}
```

and markup:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{playersReportBean.list.pageSize}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{playersReportBean.rowsList}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "pageSize"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:163)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:51)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:170)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:284)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getCurrentSelectedValues(MenuRenderer.java:647)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:748)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:843)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:297)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1778)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1778)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1781)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:452)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.admin.filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:14)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What is the reason? Couldn't someone explain?

Comment: At the moment you are trying to parse it, the String you are trying to parse to a number, has the value "pageSize", not a numerical value.

Comment: Can you try this #{playersReportBean.list.size()}"

Comment: `java.util.List<T>` does not have a property like `pageSize`. Do you expect it to have such a property? Look at these lines, `javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:163)` and `javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:51)`.

Comment: Try `#{playersReportBean.pageSize}` , as pageSize is contained within `PlayersReportBean` not in `PlayerReportGeneratorList` .For  `{playersReportBean.list.pageSize}` to work , you have to add a getter for `pageSize` in `PlayerReportGeneratorList` class.

Comment: Have SAME problem and still not knowing why this doesn'nt work...

A workaround will be to create a getPAgeSize in the bean but... why it doesn't work?

Comment: @inigoD See, there may be a couple of reasons. As far as I remeber there was something wrong with the el-expression. I inquire it while debuggin javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:163). I suggest you doing the same. It may happen when you have, for instance, a managed which is a property of another managed bean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF NumberFormatException with f:setPropertyActionListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413875/jsf-numberformatexception-with-fsetpropertyactionlistener)

Answer (score 1):

About the problem:**jdk 7 doc**

> public class NumberFormatException extends IllegalArgumentException
>   Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format.

Problem seems with your `rowsList` does not resolve for Integer, Verify this you are adding in right order i.e. `rowsList.add(new SelectItem(ItemValue, ItemLabel));`

**MORE**

How I do fill `p:selectOneMenu`

```
private List<SelectItem> rowsList= new ArrayList<>(); // Initilize
//Getter Setter
```

then fill from data base query;

```
void populateRowsList(){
        rowsList=service.findAllRowsList(); // check for ItemValue,ItemLabel
}
```

Comment: `javax.faces.model.SelectItem` is a JSF 1.x style. An `<f:selectItems>` has a `var` attribute introduced since JSF 2.0. Therefore, `javax.faces.model.SelectItem` is not needed in higher/decent versions of JSF (A `List` can take any arbitrary generic type parameter removing the need to convert it into a `List<SelectItem>`). The culprit of the exception is here in this EL `#{playersReportBean.list.pageSize}`. A `java.util.List<T>` is being unexpectedly dereferenced using `pageSize` which it does not have.