# JSF NumberFormatException with f:setPropertyActionListener

Tags: jsf, datatable, el, jsf-2.2, setpropertyactionlistener

I'm getting this error with f:setPropertyActionListener and i can't figure out why:

```
HTTP Status 500 - For input string: "selectedItem"

exception:
javax.servlet.ServletException: For input string: "selectedItem"
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:667)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "selectedItem"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:157)
javax.el.ListELResolver.getType(ListELResolver.java:50)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:215)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:242)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:60)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:168)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.SetPropertyActionListenerHandler$SetPropertyListener.processAction(SetPropertyActionListenerHandler.java:209)
javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:654)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Table Class:

```
// imports omitted
public class Table<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    private E selectedItem;

    public E getSelectedItem() { return selectedItem; }

    public void setSelectedItem(E value) { selectedItem = value; }
}
```

MyTable Bean:

```
// Imports omitted
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyTable extends Table<File> {

    @PostConstruct
    public void initBean() {
        // Loading some files into the list
    }
}
```

This is the XHTML:

```
<html> <!-- Namespaces and stuff omitted -->
    <h:head>...</h:head>
    <h:body>
      <h:form>
        <h:dataTable var="item" value="#{myTable}">
          <h:column>
            <h:commandButton value="Try Me!">
              <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{myTable.selectedItem}"/>
                <!-- I'm getting a warning from eclipse here: property not found -->
            </h:commandButton>
          </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
      </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I'm using Eclipse Luna (Java EE IDE) with Tomcat 8 and JSF 2.2.11 (mojarra). Any hints are accepted, thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `myBean` bean?

Comment: That was a typo i've made trying to get together my code, thanks for pointing it out. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You kind of coded your self into a corner with your fancy bean implementation. Take a look at [the processing steps for the `f:setActionPropertyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/setPropertyActionListener.html). Your code is choking at step 3:

> If the value of the "value" expression is not null, call getType() on the "value" and "target" ValueExpressions to determine their property types

for the following reasons:

1. The EL processor has determined that `myTable` is a `List`. Because of this, it has delegated the evaluation of the expression `myTable.selectedItem` to the `javax.el.ListELResolver` class
2. The ELResolver, on encountering the `myTable` base object, determines it's a `List` and automatically assumes that the following string is referring to a list index, i.e. myTable.**selectedItem**, where `selectedItem` is supposed to be a list index (per the EL specification, the `[]` and `.` are interchangeable for lists). You can see it in action [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-el-api/8.0.1/javax/el/ListELResolver.java#ListELResolver#70). While it may not be immediately apparent in the tomcat source, if you check the comment in a  similar implementation in [Jboss for example](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.spec/jboss-javaee-all-7.0/1.0.1.Final/javax/el/ListELResolver.java#ListELResolver.getType%28javax.el.ELContext%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29), you have the following comment:

   > If the base object is a list, returns the value at the given index. **The index is specified by the property argument, and coerced into an integer**

"property argument" here is referring to the `selectedItem` portion of your expression

3. The EL processor now attempts to convert the string `selectedItem` to an integer (to be used as a list index) which in turn explodes in a `500`

You'll make your work a whole lot easier by not combining your data structure and your backing bean, like Rami. Q suggested. Much cleaner that way IMO

Comment: You solved my problem and your explanation was clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

my Answer should be a comment, but its too long for that, so i write it as an answer.

i see some "ERRORS" in your code:

1. ALL JSF Beans & objects have to be Serializable
2. if you use Generic Types, they should be Serializable TOO:
   `public class GenericObject<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {...}`
3. Setter & Getter of a JSF Object should be like (**this.attr = ...;**):
   `public void setSelectedItem(E value) { this.selectedItem = value;}`
4. be sure that you import the managedBean correctly:
   `import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;`
5. instead of `<h:dataTable var="item" value="#{myTable}">` you should use `<h:dataTable var="item" value="#{myTable.items}">`

   and declare **items** as List Attribute of your bean with getter and setter

Comment: Hi! java.util.List is implementing Serializable. I've omitted the serialVersionUIDs because i was rewriting my code to be more clear, but thank you for pointing it out.